# Manually insert KeyPoints and get their Descriptors OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, keypoint, feature-descriptor

I got the coordinates and size of `keypoints` and want to insert them manually to get their descriptors, i tried following but it doesn't work:

```
Mat img1 = imread(imgPath1,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

float x,y;

x = getXCoord(coordList);

y = getYCoord(coordList);

vector < KeyPoint > keyPointRead;

keyPointRead.push_back(new KeyPoint(x,y,4,-1,0,0,-1)); // here is the problem i guess

Mat outputArray;

vector < KeyPoint > outputKeyPoints;

detector(img1,Mat(),keyPointRead,outputArray,true);
```

Comment: Maybe you give us more info why you think it doesn't work? I try your code. It work with one amendment `keyPointRead.push_back(*(new KeyPoint(1, 2,4,-1,0,0,-1)));`

Comment: i just fixed it; keyPointRead.push_back( KeyPoint(x,y,4,-1,0,0,-1));   the "new" was wrong, now you can enter your own keypoints! thanks for help :)